Why are some ball mount shanks angled at the rear?
I've noticed that some trailer hitch ball mounts are angled at the rear of the shank.

https://www.cabelas.com/shop/en/trailer-valet-blackout-series-10000-adjustable-drop-hitch
What is the purpose of that angle? Does it solve a problem for the user, or is it a manufacturing quirk, such as using less steel?

This hitch has a sticker on it that says "Easy Load Angle".

https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/reese-towpower-carbon-forged-ball-mount-2-x-4-in-drop-0403017p.html?rq=reese+towpower+carbon+forged+ball+mount#srp
My guess is the pointed part is easier to fit in the hitch receiver than a square tube.

That was my first thought when I saw this question. One would usually tilt a square-ended bar upon insertion, effectively for the same reason this is angled. Seems like a marketing forced engineering/production change.

Agree with @fred_dot_u - seems to me to be a marketing gimmick. Every receiver I've ever seen is squared at the end. I've inserted my 2" square receiver into the socket dozens of times and never had an issue or even thought it needed to be anything other than square. In fact I've never even really thought about it because it's never been an issue.
